# Is there a way to tell which files I accidentally renamed to *.jpg aren't actually JPEG images?

Tags: command-line, preview, graphics

I have a folder with many thousands of files, which due to an error had their extensions misnamed, all files now have the `.jpg` extension.

In all the `.jpg` files I would like to find the non-image files.

Is there a command-line way to identify which files are an actual image and which files are not?

I thought of looking for files without a preview, but cannot find a way to search files without a preview.

Here's an axample file that has a `.jpg` extension, but is not a real image:

[image]

Comment: One more reason why file name extensions should not be used to control what type of file a file is.

Comment: @GlenYates technically, they don't. The extension is what is used by OSes to determine what file handler to use. That's really all.

Comment: @Logarr Exactly because they don't control what a file _actually_ is, what I meant to convey was that file extensions should not be used by OSes to determine file associations. Not all OSes use file extensions for this.

Comment: @GlenYates I'd rather have predictable behaviour based on file name extensions than the mess that could otherwise result. See, for example: [Does X-Content-Type-Options really prevent content sniffing attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12896/does-x-content-type-options-really-prevent-content-sniffing-attacks) and [this answer to "Using file extension and MIME type (as output by file -i -b) combination to determine unsafe files?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7506/using-file-extension-and-mime-type-as-output-by-file-i-b-combination-to-dete/7531#7531).

Comment: @GlenYates If you can invent a better method, I'm sure you could make *a lot* of money licensing that method to Microsoft and Apple, because that would be quite a paradigm shift in OS user interface design.

Comment: @TylerH Well, Apple was one of the ones that does not use extensions, they used Type/Creator codes. Another example is BeOS they use MIME type.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `file FILENAME` to determine the type of data in a file.

```
$ file image.jpg text.jpg pdf.jpg
image.jpg: JPEG image data
text.jpg:  ASCII text
pdf.jpg:   PDF document, version 1.4
```

So, `file *.jpg | grep -v JPEG` should give a list of all non-JPEGs with the ".jpg" extension

Also, assuming there are PDFs you can rename them in one go

```bsh
find . -type f \
    -exec sh -c 'file "$1" | grep -q PDF' _ {} \;  \
    -exec sh -c 'echo mv -- "$1" "${1%%jpg}pdf"' _ {} \;
```

Remove the `echo`  in the second line once you verified that the output looks ok.

Comment: And specific to this question, `file *.jpg|grep -v JPEG` should give a list of all non-JPEGs with the ".jpg" extension.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, that was indeed missing from the answer :-)